# Processing stuck at 7 percent

Tags: dailymotion-api

I'm trying to upload a video using the API. I can successfully authenticate, upload and create a video and receive a video id. But when I query the processing status using `https://api.dailymotion.com/video/{VideoId}?fields=status%2Ctitle%2Cpublishing_progress` URL, it keeps returning `"publishing_progress": 7` no matter how long I wait.

If I try to upload the same video using the website directly it will process it just fine.

I wonder if anyone else has encountered this issue and know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with the source URL you associated to the video.

Have you correctly filled the URL field at the video creation [(STEP 4.)](https://developer.dailymotion.com/guides/upload/#upload-create) with the URL returned by the API when you uploaded your video [(on STEP 3.)](https://developer.dailymotion.com/guides/upload/#upload-video-steps)?

If so, you would encourage you to contact [our support](https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) with more details to dig further into possible issues

Comment: Thanks, I double-checked and I'm making the requests correctly. I even tried to upload using an external link but I got the same result. One thing I noticed is if I publish a smaller file like 40 MB it works just fine but if the file is above 100 MB it'll stop at 7 percent.